# HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Tags: java, tomcat

I am using apache tomcat server. I have written this ResponseServlet.java file but when I try to access it I obtain an error. This is the ResponseServlet.java file which is saved in the ajaxgreetings folder. I compiled it and saved the ResponseServlet.class file in the ajaxgreetings/WEB-INF/classes folder

```
import java.io.*;
import jakarta.servlet.*;
import jakarta.servlet.http.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class ResponseServlet extends HttpServlet{
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        try{
            String name = request.getParameter("name");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            if(name == null){
                out.println("No name has been given.");
                return;
            }

            out.println(getGreeting() + name);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }               
    }

    String getGreeting(){
        switch((new Random()).nextInt(5)){
        case 0: return "Hello, ";
        case 1: return "Nice to meet you, ";
        case 2: return "Hi, ";
        case 3: return "Yo, ";
        case 4: return "Hey, ";
        }
        return "Hello, ";
    }
}
```

This is the web.xml file code saved in the ajaxgreetings/WEB-INF folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee
                      https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
  version="5.0">

  <display-name>A greetings application</display-name>
  <description>Asks the user's name and then greets them</description>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ResponseServlet</servlet-name>
    <description>Performs the actual greeting</description>
    <servlet-class>ResponseServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ResponseServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/response</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

When I enter the url http://localhost:8888/ajaxgreetings/response in my browser I obtain the following error. I don't understand why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing that error, beacause when you enter your url in browser and hit enter, you are performing `GET` request, while on server side are handling post requests.

**The doPost() method in servlets is used to process the HTTP POST requests.**

So, you need to use [doGet()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doGet%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29)

See: [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doPost-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-)

Answer (score 0):

By looking into your code, it seems you need [doPost](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doPost%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29)() in your `ResponseServlet` instead of [doGet](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doGet%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29)().

So for doPost, you may need to accept `name` via any jsp which will then pass that information to your doPost(), after submission.

Comment: I have an index.html file with a form to enter a name and press a button. On pressing the button it should obtain data from http://localhost:8888/ajaxgreetings/response(ResponseServlet.java) and change its content but its also not working. When I press the button nothing happens

Comment: I have set method="post" in that form but still not working

Comment: your `ResponseServlet ` is there for accepting inputs & not returning response to `index.html`. So can you please see if there is any mapping in web.xml which you need to look at.

Comment: Or maybe my index.html file has a problem. What do you say?

Comment: that can be one of possibility as its not shared in question.

Comment: Or should I add like <form method="post" action="ResponseServlet"> in my index.html file didn't put that action part

Comment: yeah, you can give it a go.

Comment: If my ResponseServlet is there only for accepting Inputs then why does it have the out.println(). I obtained this code from this notes https://www.cs.uct.ac.za/mit_notes/web_programming/html/ch20s05.html

Comment: URL you have given for reference is pretty clear, so you need to load your `index.html`, & it will eventually passing `name` to  your responseServlet. Now in your responseservlet, you are using out.println which will return response as input name along with HTTP status.  So in nutshell, when you start your code, you need to open index.html `http://localhost:8888/ajax-greetings/index.html & submit your name.